# perl string to array with repetition operator

Tags: perl, search, replace, repeat

I have a string, say: "5 3*3 4*1 6*3 14*4 3*2 2*3 4"

I want this string to become an array with elements:

@array = ( "5", "3" x 3, "1" x 4, "3" x 6, "4" x 14, "2" x 3, "3" x 2, "4" );

I'm guessing there's a better (shorter) way than this:

```
$string = "5 3*3 4*1 6*3 14*4 3*2 2*3 4";
@array = split (/\s+/,$string);
foreach(@array) {
   if ( /\*/ ) {
      s/^(\d+)\*(\d+)/"$2" x $1/g;
   } else {
      print "$_\n";
      $_ = '"'. $_ .'"';
   }
}
```

EDIT: This code actually does what I say it should do above in the original question. But it's not actually what I want. I want the final array to look like:

@array = (5, 3, 3, 3, ...)

Comment: Do you want `(5, 3, 3, 3...)` for example? Or maintain the string as you have in the original?

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying. I just realized the ambiguity. I want what you've guessed: (5, 3, 3, 3, ...)

Comment: I'm confused now, does my code do what you want?  It sounds like you want to use the repetition operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Algorithm:

1. Take the string and split it at spaces
2. If the /(\d+)*(\d+)/ regex matches an element, we do the list element repetition. Else, we pass the element through unchanged.

#### Implementation (oneliner)

```
perl -MData::Dumper -E'$string = "5 3*3 4*1 6*3 14*4 3*2 2*3 4"; @array = map{/(\d+)\*(\d+)/ ? ($2)x$1 : $_} split /\s+/, $string; say Dumper \@array'
```

#### Implementation (normal)

```
my $string = "5 3*3 4*1 6*3 14*4 3*2 2*3 4";
my @array = map {/(\d+)\*(\d+)/ ? ($2)x$1 : $_} split /\s+/, $string;
# do something with @array:
say "@array";
```

Do note that the repetition operator used on strings repeats and concatenates the strings:

```
"a"x3 ~~ "aaa"
```

But used on a list, it returns a list with repeated elements:

```
[(1)x3] ~~ [1,1,1]
[(1,2)x2] ~~ [1,2,1,2]
```

Comment: Thank you. That does the trick. I tinkered with the map function (reading perldoc perlop, etc) but still don't quite grasp it. Do you have a good resource that describes it for The Simple, like me?

Comment: @MarkWayne The `map` function is explained in the [perlfunc page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). It takes a list on the right, performs an action on it, and stuffs the result into the list on the left. In my code, I use the fact that it can output any number of new list elements.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing your print statement in your if block, but this is an alternative:

```
$string = "5 3*3 4*1 6*3 14*4 3*2 2*3 4";
$string =~ s/\s+/#/g;                     # change space delimiter to something else
$string =~ s/(?<!\*)(\d+)(?!\*)/"$1"/g;   # quote nums that don't have an asterisk next to it
$string =~ s/(\d+)\*(\d+)/"$2" x $1/g;    # make all changes at once
@array = split (/#/,$string);             # split the string
```

I think your method is more clear, though; which is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Do a string replace and split on the space.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = "5 3*3 4*1 6*3 14*4 3*2 2*3 4";
$string =~ s/\*/x/g;
my @list = split(' ', $string );
warn Dumper( \@list );
```

Comment: Thanks. No, this isn't the right idea. The numbers must be reversed in order and repeated a number of times corresponding to the digit before the '*'.